# Openrefine does not fetch the entire html code

Tags: web-scraping, openrefine, grel

I've been fetching the academic articles in Wiley to collect author information, but the fetched column does not contain all the code.

For instance, if I inspect a site (e.g., https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1475-6773.13088), while there are more than 100 span tags, my fetched result has less than 30 span tags. Some meta tags are missing as well.

I am specifically looking for the elements like , meta tags with citation_author and citation_author_institution.

Comment: You don't say whether you are creating a project from that URL or adding a column by fetching it. For the latter, I get 403 Forbidden with OpenRefine 3.4.1. Are you sending non-default headers? I can assure you that Refine keeps everything that is sent, so I'd like at reasons that perhaps the web site isn't sending what you think it is (e.g. anti-scraping measures).

Comment: @TomMorris I added a column by fetching it and I did not receive any error (e.g. 403): I captured the html code. Maybe Wiley prevents the entire scraping.

Comment: OpenRefine doesn't capture the error by default. Try clicking the "Store error" checkbox on the Fetch URL dialog. My previous message should have said "I'd *look* at reasons".

Comment: @TomMorris Thanks. I tried with Python and I got 403 error. While I could avoid the error using a user agent, I still cannot grab the entire code. Can Openrefine or Python bypass these anti measures?

Comment: `$ curl -L https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1475-6773.13088` returns 
"Wiley Online Library requires cookies for authentication and use of other site features; therefore, cookies must be enabled to browse the site. Detailed information on how Wiley uses cookies can be found in our Privacy Policy [https://www.wiley.com/en-us/privacy]." OpenRefine doesn't support cookies, but Python can be configured to.